# Magento 2.3.5 fresh installtion using composer results in error

Tags: magento2

I am trying to install Magento 2.3.5 using composer.

muk@muk:/var/www/html$ **composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.3.5 magento23**

```
Creating a "magento/project-community-edition" project at "./magento23"
Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.3.5-p1)
  - Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.3.5-p1): Loading from cache
Created project in /var/www/html/magento23
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 463 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing magento/magento-composer-installer (0.1.13): Loading from cache
  - Installing laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin (1.0.3): Loading from cache
Plugin installation failed (include(/var/www/html/magento23/vendor/laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin/src/DependencyRewriterPlugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory), rolling back
  - Removing laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin (1.0.3)


  [ErrorException]
  include(/var/www/html/magento23/vendor/laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin/src/DependencyRewriterPlugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

I am getting following error.

```
Plugin installation failed (include(/var/www/html/magento23/vendor/laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin/src/DependencyRewriterPlugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory), rolling back
      - Removing laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin (1.0.3)
```

**My Composer version**

```
muk@muk:/var/www/html$ composer --version

Composer version 1.10.5 2020-04-10 11:44:22
```

I am using VirtualBox with Shared folder.

How can I fix it?

*Note*: To fix it I stopped using shared folder. Now I keep the entire code in the VM and do not use shared folder. For file synching I am using mutagen.

Comment: Did you end up fixing this? I think I've got the same issue

Comment: No @Erfan still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone runs into this issue, it looks to be a problem with virtualBox and shared folders.  when unzipping files, they are not immediately available in the environment.

the solution is by [rkamp](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9627#issuecomment-778420647) and is also available here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66413857/1470145

in short, one needs to override unzip to add a brief delay after unzipping.

Answer (score -1):

I thought I had the same issue, but turned out it was something else.

The upgrade went OK for me, for a sandbox/clean 2.3.4 install, and a client project running 2.3.4.

A few things:

- This could possibly be an issue with your cache, try to clear your composer laminas cache (`~/.composer/cache/files/laminas` usually)
- Although it would complain about that, you've possibly got unmet platform requirements (php version, etc.)
- Try clearing your entire composer cache (`~/.composer`)
- Double-check the repository URL (should it be 2.3.5 or 2.3.5-p1?)

Hope that helps

Comment: non of these worked, I am using VirtualBox with Shared folder.