# Composer 2.0.8 issue package-versions-deprecated

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

Using php 7.2

```
- Installing composer/package-versions-deprecated (1.8.0): Extracting archive                                                                                                                                                               
Plugin initialization failed (include(/home/vagrant/.../vendor/composer/package-versions-deprecated/src/PackageVersions/Installer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory), uninstalling plugin                          
  - Removing composer/package-versions-deprecated (1.8.0)                                                                                                                                                                                     
    Install of composer/package-versions-deprecated failed                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  Could not delete /home/vagrant/.../vendor/composer/package-versions-deprecated/src:
```

I am using laravel homestead and seeing this and can't figure what the issue is. I have removed and added the laravel homestead box multiple times as to start from scratch. However, every time I get this issue after a fresh install. It is also not listed in composer.json.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "arcanedev/log-viewer": "^5.1",
        "asvae/laravel-api-tester": "^2.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.101",
        "bepsvpt/secure-headers": "^5.3",
        "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.8",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/couchdb": "^1.0@beta",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.7",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.0",
        "gluedev/laravel-stackdriver": "^0.1.2",
        "google/cloud": "^0.96.0",
        "google/protobuf": "^3.8",
        "graylog2/gelf-php": "^1.6",
        "hoa/console": "^3.17",
        "ircmaxell/random-lib": "^1.2",
        "kitetail/zttp": "^0.6.0",
        "ktamas77/firebase-php": "^2.2",
        "langleyfoxall/laravel-nist-password-rules": "^4.1",
        "laravel/framework": "6.18.22",
        "laravel/passport": "^9.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel-notification-channels/twilio": "^3.1",
        "league/csv": "^9.1",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "league/flysystem-azure-blob-storage": "^0.1.6",
        "league/flysystem-cached-adapter": "^1.0",
        "league/flysystem-rackspace": "^1.0",
        "league/flysystem-sftp": "^1.0",
        "league/flysystem-webdav": "^1.0",
        "league/flysystem-ziparchive": "^1.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "mollie/polyfill-libsodium": "^1.1",
        "nexmo/client": "^1.8",
        "nyholm/psr7": "^1.1",
        "ocramius/package-versions": "1.4.2",
        "opencensus/opencensus-exporter-stackdriver": "~0.1",
        "pda/pheanstalk": "^4.0",
        "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "^2.9",
        "php-console/php-console": "^3.1",
        "phpseclib/mcrypt_compat": "^1.0",
        "phpunit/php-invoker": "^2.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "propaganistas/laravel-intl": "^3.0",
        "propaganistas/laravel-phone": "^4.2",
        "psr/event-dispatcher": "^1.0",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~3.4.1",
        "ramsey/uuid-doctrine": "^1.5",
        "rbdwllr/reallysimplejwt": "^2.0.42",
        "rollbar/rollbar": "^1.8",
        "ruflin/elastica": "^6.1",
        "spatie/flysystem-dropbox": "^1.1",
        "spatie/laravel-fractal": "^5.6",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.6",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.3",
        "symfony/config": "^4.3",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^4.3",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "^4.3",
        "symfony/expression-language": "^4.3",
        "symfony/lock": "^4.3",
        "symfony/translation": "4.3.8",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.3",
        "titasgailius/search-relations": "^1.0",
        "true/punycode": "^2.1",
        "twilio/sdk": "^6.10",
        "unicodeveloper/laravel-password": "1.0.*",
        "voiceit-php/voiceit2": "^3.0",
        "whoops/soap": "^1.0",
        "wildbit/swiftmailer-postmark": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.3",
        "beyondcode/laravel-er-diagram-generator": "^0.2.2",
        "coderello/laravel-populated-factory": "^0.3.0",
        "facade/ignition": "^1.16",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

My global composer.json on my windows machine...

```
{
    "require": {
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.4",
        "laravel/installer": "^3.0",
        "cretueusebiu/valet-windows": "^2.1"
    }
}
```

I have only ran `composer install` and get this on a fresh install. My code base was originally built on composer v1 and I am attempting to migrate the namespacing to psr-4 updates and ran into this issue.

I am able to run if I run `composer install --no-plugins`. However, I am not able to find where the plugin could be installed. I ran this within my laravel app root directory.

output

```
➜  ... git:(develop) ✗ rm -rf vendor
➜  ... git:(develop) ✗ composer clear-cache
Cache directory does not exist (cache-vcs-dir):
Clearing cache (cache-repo-dir): /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo
Clearing cache (cache-files-dir): /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/files
Clearing cache (cache-dir): /home/vagrant/.cache/composer
All caches cleared.
➜  ... git:(develop) ✗ rm composer.lock
➜  ... git:(develop) ✗ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 259 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking arcanedev/log-viewer (5.2.0)
  - Locking arcanedev/support (5.2.0)
  - Locking asvae/laravel-api-tester (2.0.11)
  - Locking aws/aws-sdk-php (3.166.2)
  - Locking barryvdh/laravel-debugbar (v3.5.1)
  - Locking bepsvpt/secure-headers (5.6.0)
  - Locking beyondcode/laravel-er-diagram-generator (0.2.3)
  - Locking beyondcode/laravel-websockets (1.9.0)
  - Locking cache/adapter-common (1.1.0)
  - Locking cache/tag-interop (1.0.1)
  - Locking cboden/ratchet (v0.4.3)
  - Locking coderello/laravel-populated-factory (0.3.2)
  - Locking commerceguys/intl (v1.0.7)
  - Locking composer/package-versions-deprecated (1.8.0)
  - Locking defuse/php-encryption (v2.2.1)
  - Locking divineomega/do-file-cache (v2.0.6)
  - Locking divineomega/do-file-cache-psr-6 (v2.0.1)
  - Locking divineomega/laravel-password-exposed-validation-rule (v2.3.0)
  - Locking divineomega/password_exposed (v3.1.1)
  - Locking divineomega/psr-18-guzzle-adapter (v1.1.0)
  - Locking dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (v0.1.1)
  - Locking doctrine/annotations (1.11.1)
  - Locking doctrine/cache (1.10.2)
  - Locking doctrine/collections (1.6.7)
  - Locking doctrine/common (3.1.0)
  - Locking doctrine/couchdb (1.0.0-beta4)
  - Locking doctrine/dbal (2.12.1)
  - Locking doctrine/event-manager (1.1.1)
  - Locking doctrine/inflector (2.0.3)
  - Locking doctrine/instantiator (1.4.0)
  - Locking doctrine/lexer (1.2.1)
  - Locking doctrine/orm (2.8.1)
  - Locking doctrine/persistence (2.1.0)
  - Locking dragonmantank/cron-expression (v2.3.1)
  - Locking egulias/email-validator (2.1.24)
  - Locking elasticsearch/elasticsearch (v6.7.2)
  - Locking evenement/evenement (v3.0.1)
  - Locking facade/flare-client-php (1.3.7)
  - Locking facade/ignition (1.16.4)
  - Locking facade/ignition-contracts (1.0.2)
  - Locking fideloper/proxy (4.4.1)
  - Locking filp/whoops (2.9.1)
  - Locking firebase/php-jwt (v5.2.0)
  - Locking fzaninotto/faker (v1.9.1)
  - Locking giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php (8.12.14)
  - Locking giggsey/locale (1.9)
  - Locking gluedev/laravel-stackdriver (0.1.2)
  - Locking google/auth (v1.14.3)
  - Locking google/cloud (v0.96.0)
  - Locking google/common-protos (0.1.0)
  - Locking google/gax (0.38.2)
  - Locking google/grpc-gcp (0.1.5)
  - Locking google/protobuf (v3.14.0)
  - Locking graham-campbell/guzzle-factory (v3.0.4)
  - Locking graylog2/gelf-php (1.6.5)
  - Locking grpc/grpc (1.34.0)
  - Locking guzzle/guzzle (v3.8.1)
  - Locking guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.5.5)
  - Locking guzzlehttp/promises (1.4.0)
  - Locking guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.7.0)
  - Locking guzzlehttp/ringphp (1.1.1)
  - Locking guzzlehttp/streams (3.0.0)
  - Locking hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.1)
  - Locking hoa/consistency (1.17.05.02)
  - Locking hoa/console (3.17.05.02)
  - Locking hoa/event (1.17.01.13)
  - Locking hoa/exception (1.17.01.16)
  - Locking hoa/file (1.17.07.11)
  - Locking hoa/iterator (2.17.01.10)
  - Locking hoa/protocol (1.17.01.14)
  - Locking hoa/stream (1.17.02.21)
  - Locking hoa/ustring (4.17.01.16)
  - Locking ircmaxell/random-lib (v1.2.0)
  - Locking ircmaxell/security-lib (v1.1.0)
  - Locking jakub-onderka/php-console-color (v0.2)
  - Locking jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.4)
  - Locking kitetail/zttp (v0.6.0)
  - Locking ktamas77/firebase-php (2.2.2)
  - Locking laminas/laminas-diactoros (2.5.0)
  - Locking laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge (1.1.1)
  - Locking langleyfoxall/laravel-nist-password-rules (v4.3.0)
  - Locking laravel-notification-channels/twilio (3.1.2)
  - Locking laravel/framework (v6.18.22)
  - Locking laravel/passport (v9.3.1)
  - Locking laravel/tinker (v2.5.0)
  - Locking lcobucci/jwt (3.4.1)
  - Locking league/commonmark (1.5.7)
  - Locking league/csv (9.6.1)
  - Locking league/event (2.2.0)
  - Locking league/flysystem (1.1.3)
  - Locking league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (1.0.29)
  - Locking league/flysystem-azure-blob-storage (0.1.6)
  - Locking league/flysystem-cached-adapter (1.1.0)
  - Locking league/flysystem-rackspace (1.0.5)
  - Locking league/flysystem-sftp (1.0.22)
  - Locking league/flysystem-webdav (1.0.9)
  - Locking league/flysystem-ziparchive (1.0.3)
  - Locking league/fractal (0.19.2)
  - Locking league/iso3166 (3.0.0)
  - Locking league/mime-type-detection (1.5.1)
  - Locking league/oauth2-server (8.2.3)
  - Locking maximebf/debugbar (v1.16.4)
  - Locking microsoft/azure-storage-blob (1.5.1)
  - Locking microsoft/azure-storage-common (1.5.0)
  - Locking mikemccabe/json-patch-php (0.1.0)
  - Locking mockery/mockery (1.4.2)
  - Locking mollie/polyfill-libsodium (v1.1.1)
  - Locking monolog/monolog (1.25.5)
  - Locking mtdowling/jmespath.php (2.6.0)
  - Locking myclabs/deep-copy (1.10.2)
  - Locking nesbot/carbon (2.42.0)
  - Locking nexmo/client (1.9.1)
  - Locking nexmo/client-core (1.8.1)
  - Locking nikic/php-parser (v4.10.3)
  - Locking nunomaduro/collision (v3.1.0)
  - Locking nyholm/psr7 (1.3.2)
  - Locking opencensus/opencensus (v0.5.2)
  - Locking opencensus/opencensus-exporter-stackdriver (v0.1.0)
  - Locking opis/closure (3.6.1)
  - Locking paragonie/certainty (v2.8.0)
  - Locking paragonie/constant_time_encoding (v2.4.0)
  - Locking paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.99)
  - Locking paragonie/sodium_compat (v1.14.0)
  - Locking pda/pheanstalk (v4.0.3)
  - Locking phar-io/manifest (2.0.1)
  - Locking phar-io/version (3.0.3)
  - Locking php-amqplib/php-amqplib (v2.12.1)
  - Locking php-console/php-console (3.1.8)
  - Locking php-http/discovery (1.13.0)
  - Locking php-http/guzzle6-adapter (v1.1.1)
  - Locking php-http/httplug (v1.1.0)
  - Locking php-http/message-factory (v1.0.2)
  - Locking php-http/promise (1.1.0)
  - Locking phpdocumentor/graphviz (1.0.4)
  - Locking phpdocumentor/reflection-common (2.2.0)
  - Locking phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (5.2.2)
  - Locking phpdocumentor/type-resolver (1.4.0)
  - Locking phpoption/phpoption (1.7.5)
  - Locking phpseclib/mcrypt_compat (1.0.11)
  - Locking phpseclib/phpseclib (2.0.29)
  - Locking phpspec/prophecy (1.12.1)
  - Locking phpunit/php-code-coverage (7.0.14)
  - Locking phpunit/php-file-iterator (2.0.3)
  - Locking phpunit/php-invoker (2.0.1)
  - Locking phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1)
  - Locking phpunit/php-timer (2.1.3)
  - Locking phpunit/php-token-stream (4.0.4)
  - Locking phpunit/phpunit (8.5.13)
  - Locking predis/predis (v1.1.6)
  - Locking propaganistas/laravel-intl (3.1.0)
  - Locking propaganistas/laravel-phone (4.2.7)
  - Locking psr/cache (1.0.1)
  - Locking psr/container (1.0.0)
  - Locking psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0)
  - Locking psr/http-client (1.0.1)
  - Locking psr/http-factory (1.0.1)
  - Locking psr/http-message (1.0.1)
  - Locking psr/log (1.1.3)
  - Locking psr/simple-cache (1.0.1)
  - Locking psy/psysh (v0.10.5)
  - Locking punic/punic (3.5.1)
  - Locking pusher/pusher-php-server (v4.1.4)
  - Locking rackspace/php-opencloud (v1.16.0)
  - Locking ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3)
  - Locking ramsey/uuid (3.9.3)
  - Locking ramsey/uuid-doctrine (1.6.0)
  - Locking ratchet/rfc6455 (v0.3)
  - Locking rbdwllr/reallysimplejwt (2.1.0)
  - Locking react/cache (v1.1.0)
  - Locking react/dns (v1.4.0)
  - Locking react/event-loop (v1.1.1)
  - Locking react/http (v1.2.0)
  - Locking react/promise (v2.8.0)
  - Locking react/promise-stream (v1.2.0)
  - Locking react/promise-timer (v1.6.0)
  - Locking react/socket (v1.6.0)
  - Locking react/stream (v1.1.1)
  - Locking ringcentral/psr7 (1.3.0)
  - Locking rize/uri-template (0.3.2)
  - Locking rollbar/rollbar (v1.8.1)
  - Locking ruflin/elastica (6.1.1)
  - Locking sabre/dav (4.1.3)
  - Locking sabre/event (5.1.2)
  - Locking sabre/http (5.1.1)
  - Locking sabre/uri (2.2.1)
  - Locking sabre/vobject (4.3.3)
  - Locking sabre/xml (2.2.3)
  - Locking scrivo/highlight.php (v9.18.1.5)
  - Locking sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (1.0.2)
  - Locking sebastian/comparator (3.0.3)
  - Locking sebastian/diff (3.0.3)
  - Locking sebastian/environment (4.2.4)
  - Locking sebastian/exporter (3.1.3)
  - Locking sebastian/global-state (3.0.1)
  - Locking sebastian/object-enumerator (3.0.4)
  - Locking sebastian/object-reflector (1.1.2)
  - Locking sebastian/recursion-context (3.0.1)
  - Locking sebastian/resource-operations (2.0.2)
  - Locking sebastian/type (1.1.4)
  - Locking sebastian/version (2.0.1)
  - Locking spatie/dropbox-api (1.16.1)
  - Locking spatie/flysystem-dropbox (1.2.3)
  - Locking spatie/fractalistic (2.9.1)
  - Locking spatie/laravel-fractal (5.8.0)
  - Locking spatie/laravel-permission (3.18.0)
  - Locking squizlabs/php_codesniffer (3.5.8)
  - Locking swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.2.3)
  - Locking symfony/browser-kit (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/cache (v5.2.0)
  - Locking symfony/cache-contracts (v2.2.0)
  - Locking symfony/config (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/console (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/css-selector (v5.2.0)
  - Locking symfony/debug (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/dependency-injection (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/deprecation-contracts (v2.2.0)
  - Locking symfony/dom-crawler (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/error-handler (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v1.1.9)
  - Locking symfony/expression-language (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/filesystem (v5.2.0)
  - Locking symfony/finder (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/http-client-contracts (v2.3.1)
  - Locking symfony/http-foundation (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/http-kernel (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/lock (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/mime (v5.2.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.20.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.20.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.20.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.20.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.20.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.20.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.20.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.20.0)
  - Locking symfony/process (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v2.0.2)
  - Locking symfony/routing (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/service-contracts (v2.2.0)
  - Locking symfony/translation (v4.3.8)
  - Locking symfony/translation-contracts (v1.1.10)
  - Locking symfony/var-dumper (v4.4.17)
  - Locking symfony/var-exporter (v5.2.0)
  - Locking symfony/yaml (v4.4.17)
  - Locking theseer/tokenizer (1.2.0)
  - Locking tightenco/collect (v5.8.38)
  - Locking tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.3)
  - Locking titasgailius/search-relations (1.0.6)
  - Locking true/punycode (v2.1.1)
  - Locking twilio/sdk (6.14.0)
  - Locking umpirsky/country-list (2.0.6)
  - Locking umpirsky/locale-list (1.0.0)
  - Locking unicodeveloper/laravel-password (1.0.3)
  - Locking vlucas/phpdotenv (v3.6.7)
  - Locking voiceit-php/voiceit2 (3.6.0)
  - Locking webmozart/assert (1.9.1)
  - Locking whoops/soap (1.0.0)
  - Locking wildbit/swiftmailer-postmark (3.3.0)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 259 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading composer/package-versions-deprecated (1.8.0)
  - Downloading psr/log (1.1.3)
  - Downloading symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.20.0)
  - Downloading phpoption/phpoption (1.7.5)
  - Downloading vlucas/phpdotenv (v3.6.7)
  ....
  - Downloading symfony/var-exporter (v5.2.0)
  - Downloading symfony/cache (v5.2.0)
  - Downloading symfony/expression-language (v4.4.17)
  - Downloading symfony/lock (v4.4.17)
  - Downloading symfony/yaml (v4.4.17)
  - Downloading titasgailius/search-relations (1.0.6)
  - Downloading true/punycode (v2.1.1)
  - Downloading unicodeveloper/laravel-password (1.0.3)
  - Downloading voiceit-php/voiceit2 (3.6.0)
  - Downloading whoops/soap (1.0.0)
  - Downloading wildbit/swiftmailer-postmark (3.3.0)
  - Installing composer/package-versions-deprecated (1.8.0): Extracting archive
Plugin initialization failed (include(/home/vagrant/.../vendor/composer/package-versions-deprecated/src/PackageVersions/Installer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory), uninstalling plugin
  - Removing composer/package-versions-deprecated (1.8.0)
    Install of composer/package-versions-deprecated failed


  [RuntimeException]
  Could not delete /home/vagrant/.../vendor/composer/package-versions-deprecated/src:
```

Comment: Seems pretty clear, the plugin in question is not installed. Remove mention of it from your `composer.json`. See also [the documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md#using-plugins).

Comment: @miken32 It is not in my composer.json

Comment: You're missing a [mcve] along with the *complete* output. Also, don't post pictures of text, those can't be searched and indexed. Also, consider whether writing a bug ticket is more appropriate.

Comment: @ulrichEckhardt, sorry I added more information. I am having to install with the --no-plugins flag. Not sure why that is necessary. It seems as though permissions are not correct or the package does not exist. However, I do see the sub directory stubbed out in my vendor folder.

Comment: Also @ulrichEckhardt I am able to reproduce with the above example.

Comment: Did you notice that sentence in the documentation I linked; the one about globally installed plugins? Maybe you've got one of those?

Comment: If you remove any of the packages, it doesn't show the behaviour? Sorry, I don't believe that. Also, please quote the full output (after reducing your code to a [mcve]). Further, what is the actual command you run? Is it with or without the `--no-plugins` flag? If your output included that, it would help. Lastly, make sure your user's composer configuration doesn't have an influence, move it to a different place temporarily.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I updated my question with global composer.json and the command that I have ran that works. From what I can tell looking into the plugin. Composer itself is installing the plugin as a replacement for ocramius/package-versions for comparing installed package versions when you use composer v2 and you are not running php 7.4. https://packagist.org/packages/composer/package-versions-deprecated.

Comment: @miken32 I updated my question to include the global composer.json and it seems that it is being installed on the fly by composer. see https://packagist.org/packages/composer/package-versions-deprecated as a replacement for ocramius/packaged-versions.

Comment: Try `composer clear-cache` and then remove `composer.lock` and `vendor/composer/autoload_*.php`. What directory are you running composer from?

Comment: @miken32 I updated the question with the out put and took the steps you said. I just simply removed the vendor folder because I did not have a vendor/composer/autoload_*.php

Comment: I had listed the incorrect php version in my question.

Comment: `/home/vagrant/.../vendor` suggests a problem to me, which is why I asked what directory you are running the command from.

Comment: Sorry @miken32 It is my app root directory. However, I am not trying to display the name of my application for public consumption. I have gone through and truncated those references.

Comment: Created an issue for the package in question on github. Adding here if anyone else runs into the issue. https://github.com/composer/package-versions-deprecated/issues/21#issuecomment-741451406

Comment: Please share more details. Is there any information about why **exactly** this is failing right behind `Could not delete /home/vagrant/.../vendor/composer/package-versions-deprecated/src:`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The discussions [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9361) and [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9627) point to this being an issue with virtualbox, specifically `vboxfs` and something about newly created files (ie a zip being unzipped) not being completely ready from the host OS.

A workaround exists, where putting in a delay after zip seems to work. Credit goes to [rpkamp](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9627#issuecomment-778420647).

The below worked for me (Laravel Homestead project, php7.4, virtualbox and vagrant):

1 - Create a script named unzip, somewhere. May as well be in the root of your project (where composer.json lives). Adjust the timing if you have slower storage (e.g. hdd), like `sleep 0.9`.

```
#!/bin/sh
    
/usr/bin/unzip "$@"
sleep 0.2
```

2 - Enter the Vagrant instance (everything after this step occurs within it):

```
vagrant ssh
```

3 - Copy the script to *usr/local/bin*:

```
sudo cp /path/to/unzip /usr/local/bin
```

4 - Allow the file to be executable, with:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/unzip
```

5 - Now try running `composer` again in your site root:

```
composer install
```

Ideally this fix is temporary and removed in the future.
Keep in mind your deployment environment too; does it need this script too?

Comment: I can confirm this solution worked for me, after I set 'sleep' to 0.5.

Comment: Yeah I saw this and had not updated the answer to this. So I went ahead and set this as the answer until virtual box makes their fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Updating with latest version provided me the solution:

```
composer self-update --snapshot
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem with the virtual box filesystem. I created an issue to composer and hopefully more insight will be gained.

https://github.com/composer/package-versions-deprecated/issues/21

Answer (score 0):

The true answer here after posting an issue with composer was that there is an issue with the filesystem not being correctly in sync with the VM. In this case it was virtual box, it seems as though the issue has potentially existed for a while but as composer has sharpened their efficiency/optimization that the problem has become more prevalent. I believe they have made some updates and the issue seems to subside when using composer v2.

Comment: Why not post this insight as an edit of your earlier answer (which only contains related info rather than a solution)?